# Merge longitudinal data SAS

Tags: sas, bigdata

Okay so, I've found helpful examples but not quite what I'm looking for.

1) I have 4 waves of longitudinal data; with respondent identifiers(variable name "**AID**")

2) I'd like to merge these in **SAS**

3a) I want to keep all the variables (the variables differ across waves), so long as the respondent (AID) is present across all 4 waves.

3b)I don't care if some of the unique variables answers are missing.

4) in IN= statement in SAS requires specific variables, it looks like... I have WAY too many variables to specify each one by one.

Any bright ideas SO friends?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far ?

Comment: Your question doesn't sound entirely self consistent.  IN doesn't require a list of variables, but KEEP or RENAME does.  Do you really mean merge (horizontal, end up with 1 record per person) or do you mean set (vertical, one record per person per year/time period/whatever)?  Longitudinal data you're probably better off keeping the rows separate for each [time period].

Comment: Also - you tag this [tag:bigdata].  Can you give approximate row counts/size of data?  This may impact your advice.

Comment: libname AHD "C:\Users\asobieraj.NUNET.001\Desktop\addhealth\addhealth";   

libname w1 "C:\Users\asobieraj.NUNET.001\Desktop\addhealth\addhealth\p1wave1";
data AHD.p1wave1;
 set w1.p1wave1;
run;



libname w2 "C:\Users\asobieraj.NUNET.001\Desktop\addhealth\addhealth\p3wave2";
data AHD.p3wave2;
 set w1.p3wave2;
run;


libname w3 "C:\Users\asobieraj.NUNET.001\Desktop\addhealth\addhealth\p12wave3";
data AHD.p12wave3;
 set w1.p12wave3;
run;


libname w4 "C:\Users\asobieraj.NUNET.001\Desktop\addhealth\addhealth\p23wave4";
data AHD.p23wave4;
 set AHD.p23wave4;
run;

Comment: PROC sort data=AHD.w1;
 BY AID; run; 
PROC sort data= AHD.w2;
 BY AID; run; 
PROC sort data= AHD.w3;
 BY AID; run; 
PROC sort data= AHD.w4; 
 BY AID; run;  
data allwaves; 
by AID;
merge AHD.w1(in=a) AHD.w2(in=b) AHD.w3(in=c) AHD.w4(in=d)
if a=1 and b=1 and c=1 and d=1
run;

Comment: Joe, once the data are merged (keeping only respondents present for all 4 waves) we will have at about 16000 participants per wave x4 waves x some 3600 variables per wave. 4 waves(w1 w2 w3 w4) of with respondent identifiers(AID).